# Timezone issue with UNTIL in ical RRULE statement

Tags: python, timezone, icalendar

The following code throws an exception, which most probably pertains to the TZID replacements I needed to do to fix some other bugs. If I remove the the "UNTIL" statement from the ical string, the code works just fine.

```
from icalendar.cal import Calendar
import datetime
from dateutil import rrule
from dateutil.tz import gettz

cal_str = "BEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20171019T010000\nDTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20171019T230000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;UNTIL=20180423T191500\nX-OP-ENTRY-STATE:unlocked\nEND:VEVENT"
ical = Calendar.from_ical(cal_str)
start_time_dt = ical.get("DTSTART").dt
end_time_dt = ical.get("DTEND").dt
tzinfo = gettz(str(start_time_dt.tzinfo)) 
start_time_dt = start_time_dt.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
recurring_rule = ical.get('RRULE').to_ical().decode('utf-8')
rules = rrule.rruleset()
first_rule = rrule.rrulestr(recurring_rule, dtstart=start_time_dt)
rules.rrule(first_rule)
event_delta = end_time_dt -start_time_dt
now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
for s in rules.between(now - event_delta, now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)):
    print(s)
```

Here is the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ical_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    for s in rules.between(now - event_delta, now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 290, in between
    for i in gen:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 1362, in _iter
    self._genitem(rlist, gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 1292, in __init__
    self.dt = advance_iterator(gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 861, in _iter
    if until and res > until:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Anyone help for finding out the root cause of this error and a way to fix this?

Comment: A relevant discussion https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/620. Still I need a workaround for this problem

Answer (score 2):

First of all they fixed the exception to be more explicit in `dateutil>2.7.1` to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ical_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    first_rule = rrule.rrulestr(recurring_rule, dtstart=start_time_dt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 1664, in __call__
    return self._parse_rfc(s, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 1547, in _parse_rfc
    tzinfos=tzinfos)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 1506, in _parse_rfc_rrule
    return rrule(dtstart=dtstart, cache=cache, **rrkwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dateutil/rrule.py", line 461, in __init__
    'RRULE UNTIL values must be specified in UTC when DTSTART '
ValueError: RRULE UNTIL values must be specified in UTC when DTSTART is timezone-aware
```

The solution is to calculate the UNTIL time in UTC and add `Z` to the end of the time string as described in the RFC:

https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html

the correct RRULE string should look like this:

`cal_str = "BEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20171019T010000\nDTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20171019T230000\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;UNTIL=20180423T001500Z\nX-OP-ENTRY-STATE:unlocked\nEND:VEVENT"`

Comment: Is there any way to fix this without having to manually add the "Z" to the end of the UNTIL timestamp?